# Minimal recompilation

Tags: go, compilation

I have a go module that a lot of other modules use. I want to achieve minimal recompilation in case of a simple implementation change. How do I go about this?

For example,

```golang
package mymodule

import "fmt"

func MyFunc() {
    // old code -> fmt.Println("one")
    fmt.Println("two")
}
```

A change like this can theoretically just be relinked with the .o files of other modules after recompiling mymodule without recompiling modules that depend on it.

Does go build or any other command do this? If not, how do I achieve this?

Comment: I think [this article](https://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article) should make you stop worrying (and forget about classic approach to compilation and linking typically implemented by C and C++ compilers). The article is dated but build times had actually improved since then.

Comment: You could actually experiment yourself by using `go install` (or `go build`) with the `-x` command-line option: it makes the toolchain print out detailed log of what it does (and what was compiled and what was pulled from th cache).

Comment: go build does this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a tool/command to show me the type information stored in object files?

Answer (score 1):

This is already handled by the standard Go compiler. You need to do nothing.

In fact, it was this very use case that largely inspired the creation of Go in the first place.  You can [read more about it](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/98-languages/1183-an-interview-with-googles-go-creator.html).

> The starting point was long compile times—for some of our big software at Google, build times can be unreasonably long, even with our large distributed compilation clusters. The dependency management (or lack thereof) in C and C++ results in far too much code going through the compiler.
>
> You might say that Go was conceived while waiting for a big
> compilation.

Comment: It seems that while the go compiler is optimised in order ways that makes it blazingly fast, it appears it does not do the specific thing the question is about. Checked using a -x/-n flag with go build.

Comment: I don't know why you think Go doesn't do that. I also don't know why you think -x or -n would be a clue, those features don't even claim to reveal that level of information.

Comment: Well -x does show the commands being run. And in that, I could see that even an implementation change triggered a recompilation everything that directly and indirectly depends on it. On a more logical note, my understanding is that the buildid has an actionid and a contentid, neither of which are a hash of the exported interface of a package. So how would it even be possible to achieve this optimization? Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: It should run all the same commands, whether or not any individual packages exist in the compiler cache.

Comment: But that would mean the compile command is aware of the cache and it doesn't seem like it is. I'm saying this just based on the fact that the "ignore cache" command line flag is only available in go build and not go tool compile. And based on experimental observations, it looks like -x does not print the command (it doesn't run the command either) if the package is cached and none of its dependencies are recompiled.